# rolling two homogenous dice..

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, dice

Roll two homogenous dice until a total of 7 appears for the first time. Find the probability that the number of rolls needed is odd? **(using one of the  special distribution)**

As I know we should use geometric distribution if I'm not wrong since they ask for the total of 7 appears at the first time.

My question is:

1. why they mentioned that the dices are homogenous?
2. how can we use the geometric distribution and we don't have the probability?

Thanks,

Comment: Saying that the dice are homogenous is equivalent to saying that all the probabilities are equal.  If they aren't, then the answer would be different.  For example, if one of the dice always comes up 3, and the other always comes up 4, then the probability that the number of rolls needed is odd is 100%.

Comment: Okey I got it thank you very much @MichaelSeifert

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The probability of a total 7 is $\frac{1}{6}$ thus the special pmf (geometric)  is the following

$$\mathbb{P}[X=x]=\frac{1}{6}\cdot\left( \frac{5}{6} \right)^{x-1}$$

$x=1,2,3,4,\dots$

thus

$$\mathbb{P}[X\text{ is Odd}]=\frac{6}{11}$$

Comment: thanks for your efforts, can you explain more how we got $\mathbb{P}[X\text{ is Odd}]=\frac{6}{11}$

Comment: @David : it's a geometric series.. what about posting your efforts first? And accepting my answer?

Comment: $\frac{(1/6)(5/6)^0}{1-(5/6)^2}$ Am I right ? @tommik

Comment: @David : yes, correct!

Comment: thank you very much ;) @tommik